# How don't rotate jcrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, jcrop

i have a problem with jcrop.
I have a webpage with an image and two buttons to rotate it of +90° or -90° on its center (i use jQueryRotate), but when i use jcrop to select an area the selector is rotate too, and i don't want it rotates. I checked on internet and i found different solutions, but when i traced my code i noted jquery.Jcrop.js uses in the procedure getPos the .offset() methos and it always gives me the position of top-left corner at 0° degrees.
Is there a methos to get always the position of the new top-left corner after i rotate the image of 90, 180, 270, ecc... degrees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use separate buttons to rotate image

```
$("input[name='rotate1']").click(function() {
     $("#photo").rotate(90);
     return false;
  });

$("input[name='rotate2']").click(function() {
     $("#photo").rotate(-90);
     return false;
});
```

Comment: I already use, but the problem is not the buttons, it is jcrop, because it has not to rotate.